# Xcode 7 can't export ipa in El Capitan

Tags: xcode7, osx-elcapitan

I just upgraded El Capitan and met a problem that Xcode can't export ipa file after archive, the main reason is that the export window don't have save button. Has anyone got the same problem?

[image]

Comment: Yeah good screenshot; very informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trying, I found that the archived ipa in El Capitan will generate automatically in desktop with a folder, it's weird..